# Fast way to create cell array or 3D-Matrix without for loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization

I have one column vector and one row vector.

```
a = [1;2;3]
b = [10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90]
```

I hope to chop `b` into `[10 20 30]`, `[40 50 60]`, `[70 80 90]` and create a cell array C
such that

```
C{1} = a*[10 20 30]
C{2} = a*[40 50 60]
C{3} = a*[70 80 90]
```

without for loop. How does that become possible in MATLAB?

I also hope to have

```
a = [1;2;3]
b = [10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 110 120]
```

such that

```
C{1} = a*[10 20 30]
C{2} = a*[40 50 60]
C{3} = a*[70 80 90]
C{4} = a*[100 110 120]
```

P.S. If this is not possible, how to create a 3 dimension array D such that

```
D(:,:,1) = a*[10 20 30]
D(:,:,2) = a*[40 50 60]
D(:,:,3) = a*[70 80 90]
```

without for loop?

I also hope to have

```
a = [1;2;3]
b = [10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 110 120]
```

such that

```
D(:,:,1) = a*[10 20 30]
D(:,:,2) = a*[40 50 60]
D(:,:,3) = a*[70 80 90]
D(:,:,4) = a*[100 110 120]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance-wise the 3D-matrix is certainly the better choice over the cell array! First you can use [**`permute`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) to transform `a` into the 3rd dimension and [**`reshape`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) to obtain the desired base shape of your matrix (edit for your real case). Finally you need [**`bsxfun`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to perform the actual multiplication.

```
n = 3;
a = [1;2;3]
b = [10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 110 120]

%// permuting a to 3rd dimension
A = permute(a,[2,3,1])
%// reshaping b
B = reshape(b.', [], n)

%// multiplication and forming of 3D-array
out = bsxfun(@mtimes,B,A)
```

---

```
out(:,:,1) =

    10    50    90
    20    60   100
    30    70   110
    40    80   120


out(:,:,2) =

    20   100   180
    40   120   200
    60   140   220
    80   160   240


out(:,:,3) =

    30   150   270
    60   180   300
    90   210   330
   120   240   360
```

Alternative solution, depending on the interpretation:

```
%// reshaping and permuting b
B = permute(reshape(b.', n, []),[3,1,2])

%// multiplication and forming of 3D-array
out = bsxfun(@mtimes,B,a)
```

---

```
out(:,:,1) =

    10    20    30
    20    40    60
    30    60    90


out(:,:,2) =

    40    50    60
    80   100   120
   120   150   180


out(:,:,3) =

    70    80    90
   140   160   180
   210   240   270


out(:,:,4) =

   100   110   120
   200   220   240
   300   330   360
```

Comment: thanks, actually I also hope that it works for array with complex number entries. How should it be changed?

Comment: not at all, it's totally compatible with complex numbers.

Comment: oh thanks. What if `b = [10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90]` cannot be reshaped to square matrix? For example, `b = [10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 110 120]`?

Comment: actually if `b = [10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 110 120]`. I hope the `D(:,:,1) = a*[10 20 30]`, `D(:,:,2) = a*[40 50 60]`, `D(:,:,3) = a*[70 80 90]`, `D(:,:,4) = a*[100 110 120]`. How can I do that?

Comment: Is the output really correct here? Or is the correct matrices only passed to another dimension than the third?

Comment: @patrik if `b = [10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 110 120]`, `B = reshape(b, 3, [])` or `B = reshape(b, 4, [])` does not give square matrix after `bsxfun`.

Comment: @kww I corrected a mistake and included your request. Should be working now.

Comment: @thewaywewalk for that case, can you show me how to get square matrix at each layer: `D(:,:,1) = a*[10 20 30]`, `D(:,:,2) = a*[40 50 60]`, `D(:,:,3) = a*[70 80 90]`, `D(:,:,4) = a*[100 110 120]`.

Comment: @kww well, is `a = [1 2 3 4]` for that case? Does `a` always relate to the number of layers?

Comment: @thewaywewalk `a = [1; 2; 3]` still.

Comment: @kww that does not make sense then, please edit your question and include your desired output for that input. I don't like to guess anymore ;)

Comment: @kww I added an alternative solution, is it that, what you want?

Comment: yes. Is there any way to combine the reshape and permute?

Comment: @kww well, yes. -> `permute(reshape(b.', n, []),[3,1,2])` -> see edit

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39144267/2903371) using 3 dimensions will certainly give you better performance. However since the question is about cells, I will provide some tricks how to handle this using cells.

```
a = [1;2;3]; % userdata
b = [10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90,100,110,120]; % userdata
B = reshape(b,length(b)/3,3).'; % reshape b to 3-by-3 matrix and transpose
carr = mat2cell(B,[1,1,1],3); % split each row to a cell
res = cellfun(@(x) mtimes(a,x) ,carr, 'un',0); % for every cell multiplicate with a
```

So prefer a 3D matrix, but if you want cells, this is it.

**EDIT**

For an arbitary number of cells, containing b-by-3 matrices, the following can be used.

```
a = [1;2;3];
b = [10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90,100,110,120];
ncells = length(b)/3;
B = reshape(b,3,ncells).';
carr = mat2cell(B,ones(1,ncells),3);
res = cellfun(@(x) mtimes(a,x) ,carr, 'un',0);
res{:}
```

Recommended is that you use the [debugger](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html) to step through the code and investigate how `reshape` and `mat2cell` works. This will make it possible to customize this code for your needs.

Comment: for `b = [10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 110 120]`, can you show me how to get `C{1} = a*[10 20 30]`, `C{2} = a*[40 50 60]`, `C{3}= a*[70 80 90]`, `C{4} = a*[100 110 120]`?